# Is it safe to reset a quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible/safe to reset a quest? I'm looking to reset the quest "Hail Sithis". I've already completed that and fully equipped the Dawnstar Sanctuary with the money earned.

Can I reset that quest and kill the contractor as well without things glitching out? Or would that cause too much trouble all around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use setstage to reset quests that have already been completed.

Furthermore, you cannot use setstage to go back to a previous stage of a quest due how [setstage works](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Console_Command_Tutorial#SetStage_BaseID_StageNum).

Comment: So, its not possible to reset a quest to a certain stage?

Comment: @Evgeni no, you can only set quests to a stage you have not completed yet

Comment: *sad assassin* now I cant murder the contractor. Its my bowstring arm's fault.

Comment: Link is to an Oblivion reference (easy mistake).  Skyrim probably works the same way.